# Minimizing the Sum of a Ratio of Segment Lengths in a Geometric Construction

Tags: geometry

In rectangle $ABCD$, shown below, point $M$ is the midpoint of side $BC$, and point $N$ lies on $CD$ such that $DN:NC$ = $1:4$. Segment $BN$ intersects $AM$ and $AC$ at points $R$ and $S$, respectively. If $NS:SR:RB = x:y:z$, where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers, what is the minimum possible value of $x + y + z$?

[image: image of the problem]

My thought: $NS/SB = 4/5$, then $SB=SR+RB$, assuming $NS=4$, $SR=2$, $RB=3$ would satisfy the ratio, this can't be right. and I can't see a way to get relationship between $SR$ and $RB$; point mass geometry maybe?

Comment: NS/SB = 4/5, then SB=SR+RB, assuming NS=4, SR=2, RB=3 would satisfy the ratio, this can't be right. and i can't see a way to get relationship between SR and RB; point mass geometry maybe?

Comment: Next time, please include your attempt in your question, not in a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Drop from $S$ a perpendicular $SH$ to $DC$: the similitude of triangle $NSH$ with $NBC$, and of triangle $SCH$ with $ADC$ gives:
$$
{SN\over NB}={SH\over AD}={CH\over 5DN}={4DN-CH\over4DN},
$$
whence:
$$
{CH\over DN}={20\over9}
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
{SN\over NB}={4\over9}.
$$
In a similar way drop from $R$ a perpendicular $RK$ to $BC$. From the similitude of $BRK$ with $BNC$ and of $HRK$ with $HAB$ we get:
$$
{RB\over NB}={RK\over NC}={5RK\over4DC}={BK\over2BM},
\quad
{RK\over DC}={BM-BK\over BM}
$$
whence:
$$
{BK\over2BM}={RB\over NB}={5\over14}
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
{SR\over NB}=1-{SN\over NB}-{RB\over NB}={25\over126}.
$$
It follows that $NS:SR:RB=56:25:45$.

Comment: this doesn't look right, the answer should be 126

Comment: You are right: I misread the text and thought $DN/DC=1/4$. I'll correct in a few minutes.

Comment: I corrected and all should be fine now.

Comment: I found another way to doing this problem: use D as (0,0) of a coordinate system, N is (1,0), C (5,0), A is (0,a), B (5,a), M (5, a/2); with all these points one can get the line equation of NB, AC and AM, and their intersecting points S R can be solved; then the distance of NS, SR and RB can be expressed in terms of a; this will allow one calculate the ratio x:y:z, and it gives the right answer

Comment: Of course you can also do that way.